# Zillow API captcha redirect

Tags: php, http-headers, recaptcha, zillow

I am using a [PHP wrapper](https://github.com/VerticalTab/Pillow) to access the Zillow's GetDeepSearchResults API on my Windows 10 machine using the Chrome browser.

While this works just fine on my local machine running XAMPP, the same cannot be said when I am calling the API from a hosted server on a public domain.

Instead of getting the typical HTTP 200 status code, I'm getting a HTTP 302 status code. In the HTTP 302 header, there's a key named "Location" and the value is "/captcha/?dest=...". If I append that to "http://www.zillow.com", my browser takes me to a Zillow page with a reCAPTCHA box.

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to look for a return value after I submit the reCAPTCHA text, since the `<form>` has an `action=""` attribute with an empty string.

I've looked in the Zillow API documentation, but nothing mentions the reCAPTCHA redirect issue.

Comment: Were you ever able to get this solved?

Comment: The issue was that the server being used had a blacklisted IP address. It was frustrating that the API did not tell me anything about that.